# How can I prevent TFS from locking binary files in the App_Data folder?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, locks

I placed a file to be accessible by clients for download in my Web API project's App_Data folder. It worked fine on the first couple of tests, but then all of a sudden the server app complained about not having permissions to accept the file.

It turned out that the file had been automatically locked following a checkin of code. How can I prevent this file from being locked again? I simply "checked it out" of TFS, but I don't want to have to continue doing that.

At "checkin time" I can select the file in question and opt to "Exclude" it from the checkin, but it again reverts to being locked after the checkin process has completed.

Is there a way to mark a file or folder as a "no lock zone"?

Comment: That file should simply not be part of source control.

Comment: I agree, but why was it assumed to be such by TFS, and how can I tell it to cease and desist?

Comment: Is this a web site "project" (File-New Web Site), or a Web Application Project (File->New Project)? Also, are you using a local workspace? A local workspace will assume that newly-added files should be added to source control, unless it is informed otherwise.

Comment: This is a Web API app. That is my question: how do I "inform it otherwise"?

Comment: Wait, the file isn't *locked*, it's set to *read-only*, isn't it?

Comment: It has the lock icon when I check in pending; that's what causes the problem.

Comment: Yes, and how did you create the Web API app? By File->New Web Site, or File->New Project, by Add->New Web Site, or Add->New Project? Another way to put it is: does your Web API project have a .csproj file or .vbproj file? And you haven't said if you are using a local workspace.

Comment: There is a .csproj file, yes; I don't know what you mean by 'local workspace'

Comment: Why do you want this file in source control in the first place?

Comment: I don't, that's the whole point of this post.

Comment: Then take it out, problem solved!  I rewrote my answer with this data in mind.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: "You should delete these files from source control"
Yes, that's what I want to do; my question is, How?

Comment: I see.  I will add additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a confusing terminology overload here:  the file is marked as *read-only* on the filesystem.  TFS uses the term *locked* to indicate that the file is checked-out by a given user and cannot be checked-out or checked-in by other users.  The file is not *locked*, but it is *read-only*.

Team Foundation Server - when you're using a server workspace - marks the files as read-only when they are checked-in to the server and sets then to writable when the files are checked-out.

It sounds like you do not want this file in source control anyway.  You should delete these files from source control (but not from your local machine).  In the future, you should carefully review your pending changes so you do not add files that you are not interested in having in source control.

Comment: I didn't check that .exe on purpose; TFS automatically checked it in (I guess) when I did a "pending udpates" checkin. Maybe I should just explicitly check in those files that have changed, one at a time...

Comment: There should be a context menu item for files and folders that allow you to exclude a file or folder from TFS purview/monitoring.

Comment: If you're using a local workspace, then you can use the `.tfignore` functionality to exclude a file or folder.  For server workspaces, you should manually avoid adding any files you do not want checked in.

Comment: I don't want to have to resort to using command-line stuff; checking in files should be easy using a GUI.

Comment: It sounds like it's *too* easy?

Comment: Yes, my point was that it was so easy that you put a file in source control that probably doesn't belong there...

Comment: My point was I didn't put it there explicitly, and TFS shouldn't assume it belongs there, based on its file type.

Comment: It sounds like you recursively added a folder to source control.  If you did this, and didn't review the pending changes, it's not TFS's fault that it added what you told it to.  Plenty of people *do* check in binaries like DLLs and EXEs that are part of their build process.

Comment: I disagree (that it's not TFS' fault) because it's not visually marked as having changed - that would've given me a clue. And still, it should be easy/obvious to mark a file or folder as "don't touch me"